# WebApi - Swagger = List of Users not showing a Role from UserRoles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, webapi

Any suggestion where is issue, In swagger showing all details without role "role" is null, printscreen attached below.

There are my models of Identity below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and my ApiController:

[image]

My resuult in swagger where in USerRoles => role is null

[image]

Comment: You have debugged your server and have seen the role property looks correct in your userList before returning? And please don't put code as pictures here. Code is text and easily to throw in here and different from picture easily usable for us to help you. This way you make it harder for you and us.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. To have access to role & user, I added new ControllerBase for ApplicationUserRole and adding includeProperties of User, Role. Updating working fine

[image]